# Swift 4 Decoding to different models from custom JSON objects

Tags: json, swift

I have a websocket which generate different json objects. Objects could contain no any common fields

```
{
    "type": "apple",
    "kind": "fruit",
    "eatable": true
}
{
    "item": "key",
    "active": true 
}
{
    "tool": "screwdriver",
    "original": "toolBox",
    "cross-head": true
}
```

I have a list of classes for them (they could contain some logic) so I need to parse it to map some those models with some hierarchical structure e.g. 
Try to parse fruits if they fails try to parse keys if they fails try to parse toolbox. Sometimes I need to add some new classes to parse some objects and some new fields to existing classes. 
How to organize picking class for parsing?

**Update**

1. I have no control on backend data so I cannot add any fields to JSON I have.
2. Objects come one at a time. I have separate class models for most of them. The issue is to choose the right class to map the JSON fields.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you're asking and what is happening in your app. Are you receiving one object at a time or do the come in an array or some kind of tree structure and what do you mean that you need to add some classes or fields, how is that relevant to your question?

Comment: All these objects come in single response i.e. one JSON response object?

Comment: So are you requesting these objects separately? Because in that case you know beforehand what the response will be and hence what class/struct you will need to decode.

Comment: No I don't request any objects they come when they want to via websockets. That is why I don't know what data I got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

First you declare your types conforming to the `Decodable` protocole:

```
struct Fruit : Decodable {
    let type : String
    let kind : String
    let eatable : Bool
}

struct Tool : Decodable {
    let tool : String
    let original : String
    let crossHead : Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tool = "tool"
        case original = "original"
        case crossHead = "cross-head"
    }
}
```

Then you extend `Decodable` to "reverse" the use of the genericity:

```
extension Decodable {
    static func decode(data : Data, decoder : JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> Self? {
        return try? decoder.decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

You then extend `JSONDecoder` to try decodable types among the ones you want to test:

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    func decode(possibleTypes : [Decodable.Type], from data: Data) -> Any? {
        for type in possibleTypes {
            if let value = type.decode(data: data, decoder: self) {
                return value
            }
        }        
        return nil
    }
}
```

And eventually you specify the types you want to try and decode:

```
let decodableTypes : [Decodable.Type] = [Fruit.self, Tool.self]
```

You can then use it to decode your JSON:

```
let jsonString = """
    {
        "tool": "screwdriver",
        "original": "toolBox",
        "cross-head": true
    }
    """
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

let myUnknownObject = JSONDecoder().decode(possibleTypes: decodableTypes, from: jsonData)
```

And voilà!!!

Now you can add as much types as you want in your `decodableTypes` as long as they conform to the `Decodable` protocol.

It is not the best approach, because if you have many types it won't be optimal, but this way you don't need to add a discriminating field in your data.

Comment: Thanks that's what I looked for. Static extension for Decodable.

Comment: `decoder : JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()` — **do not** do this, `JSONDecoder` currently is leaking memory, if you're creating new instance each time you call your extension method you gonna have a ton of leaked memory, better create some static global instance for parameter default value.

Comment: This was just to keep the example simple, the idea was to use the `JSONDecoder` on whichever instance. This code is not meant to be used this way of course. But I used this shortcut to answer the question clearly, and not depict the way `JSONDecoder` has to be used in production code. And this is true even when there is no leak... Thanks anyway for the reminder.

Comment: This is actually a pretty bad idea. If you have 2 structs that share a bunch of common attributes ( e.g. first struct only has Int a, but the second has Int a,b) it's quite possible that decoding to the struct containing Int a works, while the incoming json has Int a, b, so you end up with the wrong object.

Answer (score 4):

Try finding the key you are looking for that model class if that key is not present in that object try another model class. This should make you determine which model class is suitable for the given object.

**Use the unique key which is not present in any other model class**

Example:

```
var array = NSArray(array: [[
    "type": "apple",
    "kind": "fruit",
    "eatable": true
    ],
    [
        "item": "key",
        "active": true
    ],
    [
    "tool": "screwdriver",
    "original": "toolBox",
    "cross-head": true
    ]])


for model in array as! [NSDictionary]
    {
        if(model.value(forKey: "type") != nil)
        {
            print("use Fruit Model Class")
        }
        else if(model.value(forKey: "item") != nil)
        {
            print("use second model class")
        }
        else
        {
            print("use third model class")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good decision but I'd like to have some more automatic ways to decide which model to use. Sometimes I need to add a new class to my project so I will have to add some rules here. Perfectly is to have some rule inside the class itself.

Comment: Add static functions to each class to check whether the given object contains that unique key which is needed for that Model Class. That will make it lot easier for you to access and use it

Comment: I think that is the best you can do to determine the model of that given object.

Comment: I think so... Unfortunately.

Comment: Don't use `NSArray/NSDictionary` and `value(forKey` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system.

Comment: @vadian can you please help me understand what do you mean by "You are fighting the strong type".

Comment: "... system". Swift is based on strong types. A Foundation `NSArray` is treated as `[Any]` (unspecified) while the Swift array can be specified at least as an array of dictionaries (`[[String:Any]]`)

Answer (score 1):

If all those fields are related or a union style, you may consider user Enum, which is also very easy to implement.

```
    let  data1 = """
    [{
        "type": "apple",
        "kind": "fruit",
        "eatable": true
    },
    {
        "item": "key",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "tool": "screwdriver",
        "original": "toolBox",
        "cross-head": true
    }]
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

    struct JSONType : Decodable{
        let type: String
        let kind: String
        let eatable : Bool
    }

    struct JSONItem : Decodable{
        let item: String
        let active : Bool
    }

    struct JSONTool : Decodable{
        let tool: String
        let original : String
        let crosshead : Bool

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case tool = "tool"
            case original = "original"
            case crosshead = "cross-head"
        }
    }

    enum JSONData : Decodable{

        case type(JSONType)
        case item(JSONItem)
        case tool(JSONTool)

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            do{ let temp = try container.decode(JSONType.self); self = .type(temp) ; return}
            catch{do { let temp = try container.decode(JSONItem.self) ; self = .item(temp) ; return}
            catch{ let temp = try container.decode(JSONTool.self)  ; self = .tool(temp) ; return}}
            try  self.init(from: decoder)
        }

        func getValue()-> Any{
            switch self {
            case let .type(x): return x
            case let .item(x): return x
            case let .tool(x): return x
            }
        }
    }


    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([JSONData].self, from: data1)
    print(result[0].getValue())
    print (result[1].getValue())
    print (result[2].getValue())
```